# How can i create a URL having - character in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, action

How can i add a `-` character in the URL using ASP.NET MVC. I have a controller called home and action name `DownloadSpiderman2PCGAMEHighlyCompressed`,
From the mentioned action the created URL is

```
http://localhost:7500/Home/DownloadSpiderman2PCGAMEHighlyCompressed
```

I want to add `-` character in to my URL i have try multiple ways couldn't find solution

**My effort**

I have rename the - in the view however the url does not reflect the - in the address.

```
 public ActionResult DownloadSpiderman2PCGAMEHighlyCompressed()
        {
            return View("Download-Spiderman2-PC-GAME-Highly-Compressed");
        }
```

My expected output should be

http://localhost:7500/Home/Download-Spiderman2-PC-GAME-HighlyCompressed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Route` Attribute as well:

```
[Route("Download-Spiderman2-PC-GAME-HighlyCompressed")]
public ActionResult DownloadSpiderman2PCGAMEHighlyCompressed()
```

Alternative way would be using `ActionName`?

```
[ActionName("Download-Spiderman2-PC-GAME-HighlyCompressed")]
public ActionResult DownloadSpiderman2PCGAMEHighlyCompressed()
```

Comment: Can i use this for controller like i have home controller can i do it like pc-games?

Comment: refer to this article it helps http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/understanding-attribute-routing-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Rout is not working ?

@Html.ActionLink(@game.GameTitle, @game.ActionName, "PC-Games", new { id = 1 })

http://localhost:7500/Home/Download-Spiderman2-PC-GAME-Highly-Compressed?Length=8

Comment: However hit to the controller recieved but the url does not reflect pc-games it show home word in the url

Comment: @JohnDoe what are you trying to do exactly? :)

Comment: URL structure 
domain/controller/action
i have added the routeprefix attribute it's not working
i want url 
http://compressgames.com/pc-games/download-compressgames

Comment: @JohnDoe alright you either want to show the url or completely change it's name so the Html.Action() will be able to find it for example, which one do you desire?